# Incorrect rendering of tiled background in Chrome

Tags: css, apache, google-chrome

I have a tiled background that doesn't render correctly in Chrome (works fine in other browsers). I have the exact same site running on another server and from this server it renders correctly across all browsers.

[image]

Here's the client code:

```
background: url("../images/bg_tile.png") repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

As it's working properly from the other server though I'm guessing it's a server thing. The server that is messing with me is running Apache version 2.2.29 and PHP 5.4.32.

Any suggestions as for what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked the rendered image on the server to make sure that it has the same dimensions/is completely the same image as it is on the proper server? It's not being converted or modified in any way?

Comment: Yeah the image seems to be in good health and isn't being converted or modified in any way.

Comment: Oh dear. This is beyond me then. If the image is exactly the same and the code is *exactly* the same, the result *should* be exactly the same...should...but it's not? o_O

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version of Chrome are you running? And is it Canary or just plain Chrome?

Comment: Mm one would think that it should give the same output.. I'm using plain Chrome version 38.0.2125.122. Seems like it's a call for help from a depressed server. The search goes on...

Comment: My guess would be you've accidentally set the zoom level in chrome for your site. Press CTRL+0 (windows) or CMD+0 (osx).

Comment: Prisoner - You're right, thanks. I'm such an idiot ;P

Comment: @oskare: please post a jsfiddle in order to allow us to try it.